# Convert list of list into numpy array without commas between each list element

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, numpy, keras

I have a list of list that looks like this:`a = [[1,1],[1,1]]`.

I would like to convert it into a numpy array that looks like this:`a = [[1,1] [1,1]]`.

Is there any way I can achieve this? I don't seem to be able to mimic the X_train dataset structure given by `keras.datasets.imdb` even though `type(X_train) = numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: `a = [[1,1] [1,1]]` doesn't seems to be a valid syntax, Why Do you want to do that

Comment: What you are asking for doesn't make sense. `[[1,1] [1,1]]` is not a valid python data structure, and looks more like a `list` than a `numpy.array`

Comment: What's wrong with `numpy.array(a)`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh but that has commas between each element...

Comment: @ZdaR Apparently `type(a)` returns numpy.ndarray. I am trying to transform my list into the specific numpy array so that I can feed it into my embedding layer in an recurrent neural network.

Comment: @user3584858 yes, but your example of what you are trying to transform it into is meaningless - it is not a valid Python literal, and it doesn't even really look like a `np.array`. You need to be *specific and precise*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am building a recurrent neural network on the keras library. The input to the neural net as shown by online examples use keras's imdb datasets. To prevent passing in the wrong input format for my own data that I've crawled and preprocessed, I have printed imdb input training datasets as well as it's type so that I can mimic exactly how it is formatted. For instance, a sentence input vector from the imdb dataset may look like this `[[1,2] [4,1]]` with type of `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: @user3584858 what is so difficult about being specific and precise. How many times does it have to be repeated: `[[1,2] [4,1]]` is *not a valid Python data structure*. You probably just want `numpy.array(a)`, and the commas are being dropped because of the environment you are printing in (maybe a notebook or something like that).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am printing everything on an ssh terminal. I tried the following data type: list, list of list, numpy.array, numpy.asarray. And, I've also tried the following outputs: keras's imdb input training data, gensim word2vec weight matrix, both of which are numpy.ndarray types.

Everything is showing as expected except for kera's imdb input training data.

Comment: @user3584858 you need to post this in your question, not as a comment. It would be helpful if you posted the exact output.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I see. Thanks

Comment: The only thing I can think of that would display like this is an array of lists, not a 2d array.

Answer (score 3):

You need to explain the `keras` target better.  The presence or not of commas is an indication of the nature of the data structure, but it is really just a display convention.

Python list uses the comma delimiter all the time:

```
In [751]: alist = [[1,2],[3,4]]
In [752]: alist
Out[752]: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

A numpy array can be displayed with and without the comma.

```
In [753]: arr=np.array(arr)
In [754]: arr
Out[754]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
In [755]: str(arr)
Out[755]: '[[1 2]\n [3 4]]'
In [756]: print(arr)
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
```

To get your mix of commas and space I'd have to make an object dtype array:

```
In [757]: a=np.empty((2,), dtype=object)
In [758]: a
Out[758]: array([None, None], dtype=object)
In [759]: print(a)
[None None]
In [760]: a[0]=[1,2]
In [761]: a[1]=[3,4]
In [762]: a
Out[762]: array([[1, 2], [3, 4]], dtype=object)
In [763]: print(a)
[[1, 2] [3, 4]]
```

I can imagine the `keras` package constructing such an array, but I wouldn't recommend it to a beginner.

---

From the keras imdb documentation

> X_train, X_test: list of sequences, which are lists of indexes (integers). If the nb_words argument was specific, the maximum possible index value is nb_words-1. If the maxlen argument was specified, the largest possible sequence length is maxlen.

It says list of lists, but it could be object dtype array of lists.  Sounds like those inner lists vary in length, which explains why it isn't a 2d array.

```
 np.array([[1,2], [3,4,5]])
```

Produces such an array.

Comment: I would like to upvote but I can't. Really appreciate your reply. Just one question: Is it alright if I assign X_train to a simple `numpy.array()`, without those object dtype array of lists that you mentioned, and use it as input to my keras recurrent neural net?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but there's a good possibility that it will work.  If my guess is right, `keras` is probably just iterating on the array, expecting a list or array each time.